# regex youtube url for embed with or without playlist

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have a function that is verifying a youtube url, and grabbing the video ID from it, and returns an embed url instead. This works great for a youtube url like "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12345678901", but when the url has a playlist, I need the playlist to work as well. What changes would need to be made to the regex to return the playlist as well if one exists?

Example playlist url:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12345678901&list=123456789_1234567890123456789-1234

```
function embedVideo(url) {
  var youtube = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/,
      yt = url.match(yt);

  if (yt) {
    return "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + yt[1];
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: your regex works https://regex101.com/r/pW3cT7/2

Comment: Yes, but I need it to add the playlist option if it exists as well. (&list=...)

Comment: you mean this https://regex101.com/r/pW3cT7/3 ?

Comment: Seems correct. If you post how it would work in the function as an answer I will test it out and mark as correct if it works.

Comment: Actually, I tested it and it works. Please add it as an answer and I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just capture also the characters after `&list=` .

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((?:\w|-){11})(?:&list=(\S+))?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pW3cT7/3)

Answer (score 1):

The brackets in the above were in slightly wrong so it did not work for url's with youtu.be should have been:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/)(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=)((?:\w|-){11})(?:&(play)?list=(\S+))?$
```